# ASPx Dev Express File Upload Control to Mapped Network Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, devexpress

Here is my function, and as you can see I have the upload going into the web sites directory/files ... I am hosting the site on IIS with another site & need the files to upload to the mapped network drive DOCSD9F1/TECHDOCS/

No idea what the folder path should be...

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            //string uploadFolder = "//DOCSD9F1/TECHDOCS/";
            string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(uploadFolder + fileName);
            e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backslashes instead of slashes for the network path.  If it doesn't work, make sure the ASP.Net account has adequate permissions to write to the share.